# any webcam stopped working (camera is working on windows)

Tags: 16.04, webcam, camera

Suddenly any webcam (integrated on USB) stopped working. For example my integrated camera (but any other USB connected camera produce the same) it works on my windows 10 partition, but it doesn't work anymore in Ubuntu 16.04. Here some commands that can be useful:

Is listed in `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:930b Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`uname -a` produces:

```
Linux name 4.4.0-189-generic #219-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 12:26:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg | grep uvcvideo` is:

```
[   20.044256] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Truevision HD (064e:930b)
[   20.044265] Modules linked in: uvcvideo(OE+) videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core hp_wmi(+) v4l2_common sparse_keymap videodev(OE) media intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp arc4 rtl8188ee kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi rtl_pci irqbypass rtlwifi mac80211 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel aesni_intel snd_hda_codec aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper snd_hda_core ablk_helper snd_hwdep cryptd joydev input_leds serio_raw snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device intel_pch_thermal snd_timer lpc_ich shpchp hp_wireless mei_me mei snd soundcore processor_thermal_device int340x_thermal_zone intel_soc_dts_iosf int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel
[   20.044334]  [<ffffffffc08bbb30>] uvc_probe+0x490/0x2aa0 [uvcvideo]
[   20.044361]  [<ffffffffc08d2024>] uvc_init+0x24/0x1000 [uvcvideo]
[   20.044412] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

No program can detect the webcam, I tried with cheese "no device found" and also skype or chrome.
In case you were wondering, I have no key to disable the webcam in my laptop (HP 15-ac194nl) and secure boot is disabled in BIOS (there no other options in BIOS reguarding the webcam). I already tried different reboots. Actually I don't know exactly when the problem appeared. Any hints?

Comment: Not really..It's the same problem (I already flagged my question as a duplicate of that) but the answer is not really an answer because I cannot uninstall librealsense, I use it..